# cargar vue component en modal bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack

Hola tengo un componente en vue estoy usando rails 5, turbolink 5 y webpack.

Si el componente lo coloco directamente en la pagina donde hace el render una ruta por ejemplo new.html.erb, el componente carga
Pero si quiero mostrar ese componente en un modal con bootstrap ya no me carga al parecer solo esta cargando el componente en el render inicial le dejo mi codigo

Este es el codigo donde cargo el componente desde un script

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import MyComponent from '../app.vue'
import MultiText from '../components/multi_text.vue'

import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks';
Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  var element= document.getElementById("este");
  if (element!=null) {
    var vueapp = new Vue({
      el: element,
      components: { MultiText}
    });
  }
});
```

Obviamente en mi html coloco el div

```
<div id="este">
      <multi-text 
        ruta-save-campos="<%= guardar_campos_proyectos_path(@proyecto) if @proyecto.id.present? %>"
        campos-proyecto= "<%= @proyecto.campos.to_json if @proyecto.campos.present? %>" > 
      <multi-text/> 
    </div>
```

Pero si lo invoco desde un modal no funciona

---Actualizacion-----
hice el import VUe y MultiText como ambito globales con las siguiente linea

```
window.Vue = Vue;
window.MultiText = MultiText;
```

Finalmente mi archivo quedo asi

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import MyComponent from '../app.vue'
import MultiText from '../components/multi_text.vue'

window.Vue = Vue;
window.MultiText = MultiText;

import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks';
Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  var element= document.getElementById("este");
  if (element!=null) {
    var vueapp = new Vue({
      el: element,
      components: { MultiText}
    });
  }
});
```

De esta manera puedo usar tanto Vue como MultiText en cualquier pagina de mi aplicacion Rails.

Comment: Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera aunque no se si sea la mas apropiada . En mi archivo .js de package de webpack añadi mi componente y vue en ambito global con las siguientes lineas

window.Vue = Vue;
window.MultiText = MultiText;

Con ello ya puedo usar de manera global en cualquier parte de mi aplicaccion mi componente asi como tambien llamar a Vue. No se si sea lo mas apropiado

Answer (score 0):

hice el import VUe y MultiText como ambito globales con las siguiente linea

```
window.Vue = Vue;
window.MultiText = MultiText;
```

Finalmente mi archivo quedo asi

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import MyComponent from '../app.vue'
import MultiText from '../components/multi_text.vue'

window.Vue = Vue;
window.MultiText = MultiText;

import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks';
Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  var element= document.getElementById("este");
  if (element!=null) {
    var vueapp = new Vue({
      el: element,
      components: { MultiText}
    });
  }
});
```

De esta manera puedo usar tanto Vue como MultiText en cualquier pagina de mi aplicacion Rails.